# Deletar arquivo Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Ao tentar deletar uma imagem de um diretorio especifico recebo a mensagem de que o arquivo não existe, porém consultando o caminho que o código esta executando eu vejo que o arquivo existe sim, e a string do caminho esta 100% correta.

Cheguei a considerar permissão mas o próprio código é quem cria a pasta, salva o arquivo dentro e lê, só que ele não apaga...

```
Storage::delete(public_path('uploads/'.$asset->contents->belongs_to.'/'.$asset->name));
```

> File not found at path: var/www/xpto-digitaldev/public/uploads/2/217dade2ab7db91d12f1bca7b0cd4c82.png

Salvando o arquivo vindo do upload;

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
   $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
   $newFileName = md5(rand(0,9999)).'.'.$extension;
   $image->move(public_path('uploads/'.$clientDirectory), $newFileName);
}
```

Comment: Não falta fechar os parentesis em `Storage::delete(public_path('uploads/'.$asset->contents->belongs_to.'/'.$asset->name);`? E se tentar `unlink(public_path('uploads/'.$asset->contents->belongs_to.'/'.$asset->name));`

Comment: @Miguel não, a função `public_path()` só espera 1 parametro, se eu tivesse esquecido de fechar o parênteses eu iria receber um erro de syntax.

Comment: Sim mas não parece que tenha fechado os do `delete(...`

Comment: Já arrumei @Miguel

Comment: Se fizer com unlink ? como lhe disse em cima

Comment: com unlink funcionou @Miguel, post sua resposta para que eu possa aprovar, vou estudar este caso tambem para ver porque o `delete` do Laravel que usa unlink não funcionou.

Comment: Talvez acrescente alguma coisa (indesejada neste caso) ao path do ficheiro a apagar. Eu custumo fazer sempre com unlink, ok vou postar a resposta. Obgado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com `Storage::delete(...)`, nunca tentei, uso sempre a função nativa de php [unlink](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unlink.php), experimente o seguinte:

```
unlink(public_path('uploads/'.$asset->contents->belongs_to.'/'.$asset->name));
```

Answer (score 1):

Dá para usar o **File**.

```
File::delete('img/imagem.png');
```

Não se esqueça do:

```
use File;
```

**File** pode ser o mesmo que **Storage**.

Answer (score 0):

Eu to usando o Storage assim e ta dando boa.

Storage::delete(["imagens/pasta/banners/arquivo.ext}"]);

colocar um array como parâmetro para os arquivos que quer excluir

Answer (score -2):

Se estiver usando a estrutura do laravel pode usar da seguinte forma:

Storage::disk('public')->delete('exports/pasta_com_arquivo/'.nome_arquivo);

OBS: Lembre-se de importar o Storage
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).